# How to Migrate TFS 2013 Database to New Hardware?

Tags: database, tfs, tfs-migration

**How to Migrate TFS 2013 Database to New Hardware ?**

How to migrate the TFS database server to a new hardware?

Comment: If you google that exact phrase you will find a ton of docs. What is your specific problem?

Comment: These are the simple steps which you can use to move TFS database server to a new hardware. I didn't find these simple steps anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**Five Step Process:**

1)  Backup and Restore backed up source databases to the new target server.

2)  Login to TFS Application server.
    a.  Stop the TFS Collections

3) Remap Databases:
    TFSConfig RemapDBs 
   /DatabaseName: NewDBServer;TFS_Configuration /SQLInstances:NewDBServerInstance
   /Continue

4) ChangeServerID:TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:NewDBServer /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration

5) RegisterDb:
  TfsConfig registerDb /sqlInstance:NewDBServer /databaseName:Tfs_Configuration